Why does calling asyncio.open_connection multiple times result in OSError?
Here is a minimal reproducer:
import asyncio


async def supervisor():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        for _ in range(20):
            tg.create_task(send())


async def send():
    _, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("localhost", 8888)
    writer.write(b"test")
    await writer.drain()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(supervisor())

This results in:
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "/tmp/repro.py", line 17, in <module>
  |     asyncio.run(supervisor())
  |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
  |     return runner.run(main)
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
  |     return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 654, in run_until_complete
  |     return future.result()
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/tmp/repro.py", line 5, in supervisor
  |     async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
  |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/taskgroups.py", line 145, in __aexit__
  |     raise me from None
  | ExceptionGroup: unhandled errors in a TaskGroup (1 sub-exception)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "/tmp/repro.py", line 11, in send
    |     _, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("localhost", 8888)
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/streams.py", line 48, in open_connection
    |     transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1113, in create_connection
    |     transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1143, in _create_connection_transport
    |     transport = self._make_socket_transport(sock, protocol, waiter)
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 61, in _make_socket_transport
    |     return _SelectorSocketTransport(self, sock, protocol, waiter,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 936, in __init__
    |     base_events._set_nodelay(self._sock)
    |   File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 196, in _set_nodelay
    |     sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    | OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
    +------------------------------------

on both Linux and Mac. If I only create a single task, then it succeeds every time. Am I misunderstanding what the StreamWriter object is? My intention here is to create multiple TCP client connections using asyncio.

Works for me (on Linux) with a test TCP echo server (copied from asyncio docs). Maybe it depends what is on the other side (port 8888).

Ok I'm an idiot. It turns out netcat doesn't support simultaneous connections whilst ncat, which is usually bundled with nmap, does. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
